# PointLables on series hide under screen near axis

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcharts

I am trying to make this chart with the help of QtCharts but the pointlabels on the series hide under screen close to the axis. The problematic portion is highlighted in the picture.
[image]

The Code for the graph function is here

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<QSplineSeries>
#include<QTimer>
#include<QPieSlice>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

QSplineSeries *series = new QSplineSeries();
series->append(0,0);
series->append(2,5);
series->append(4,6);
series->append(6,2);
series->append(8,9);
series->append(10,5);
QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->legend()->hide();
chart->addSeries(series);

chart->setTitle("Data");
QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

series->setPointLabelsVisible(true);
series->setPointLabelsFormat("@yPoint");

//QCategoryAxis *axisX = new QCategoryAxis;
QValueAxis *axisX = new QValueAxis();

axisX->setRange(0,10);
axisX->setTitleText("title x");




chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignBottom);

QValueAxis *axisY = new QValueAxis();

axisY->setRange(0,9);
axisY->setTitleText("title y");
chart->addAxis(axisY,Qt::AlignLeft);
series->attachAxis(axisY);
series->attachAxis(axisX);


chartView->setFixedHeight(300);
chartView->setFixedWidth(300);
chartView->setParent(ui->chartlayout);

}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Please add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just added minimal reproducible example.. Kindly have a look